# How can I split "Firstname LastnameFirstname2 Lastname2" to "Firstname Lastname" "Firstname2 Lastname2"?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an imported cell that has two names in it like this: "Firstname LastnameFirstname2 Lastname2". How can I split it with VBA to have one cell with "Firstname Lastname" and another cell with "Firstname2 Lastname2"? A specific example is this: split "Nick MartinezMackenzie Gore" into "Nick Martinez" and "Mackenzie Gore".

Comment: So find the first capital letter in a string of text, not one after a space. Based on your example that will be the start of the second firstname.

Comment: Find(), len() and mid() to start.

Comment: Assume that each name, first or last name, will have just the first letter capitalized. I can change any unique situations (i.e. McMillan, MacKenzie, etc.).

Comment: @solarmike yes, correct assumption

Comment: Can you verbally express the rule(s) to split "MartinezMackenzie" and "McMillanMacKenzie"?

Comment: I have used find() etc crafted to match unique regular situations but you seem to be suggesting now that the separator could be a comma or space or tab or anything. So I will let you play with the functions I suggested, hint: there are already examples on here showing their use to this type of thing.

Comment: Use powerquery. Split column " on transition from lowercase to uppercase". Available in excel 2010+

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you need to split those words(Names) which are considered as one text, then set them in the separate cells as you describe above.
If that was right try with the below **code**:

```
Sub SplitWords()
Dim TextStrng As String
Dim Result() As String

For i = 2 To 10

TextStrng = Cells(i, 1)
Result() = Split(TextStrng)
Cells(i, 2) = Result(0) & " " & Result(2)
Cells(i, 3) = Result(1)

Next i
```

result :
[image]

Comment: Output1 needs to be Nick Martinez. Output2 need to be Mackenzie Gore.

Answer (score 0):

The codes below assumed that the Input string pattern is consistent : **the first character of the firstname1, lastname1, firstname2, lastname2 is a capital letter**.
[image]

So the logic behind to get fn1 ln1 separate with fn2 ln2 is : on the third capital letter found in the Input string.

```
Sub test()
Dim rg As Range: Dim cell As Range
Dim txt As String: Dim char As String
Dim cnt As Long: Dim pos As Long

With ActiveSheet
Set rg = .Range("A2", .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

cnt = 0

For Each cell In rg
    txt = cell.Value
        For pos = 1 To Len(txt)
            char = Mid(txt, pos, 1)
            If char <> " " Then If UCase(char) = char Then cnt = cnt + 1
 
            If cnt = 3 Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(txt, pos - 1)
                cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Mid(txt, pos)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next pos
    cnt = 0
Next cell
 
End Sub
```

The process:
Create the rg variable of the input string in the active sheet column A.

Loop each row of the rg and have the value as txt variable
Then it loop to each character in txt, have the position of the char as pos variable and have the character as the value of char variable.

check, if the upper case of the char value is the same with char value itself then it create a counter in cnt variable

Once the cnt reach 3, then it means the pos(ition) is where the third char value with capital letter. So it takes the fn1 ln1 by using LEFT function and the fn2 ln2 by using the MID function.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Note that the "splitter" is just a single step -- Examine the Applied steps

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Names", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = 
        Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Names", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"a".."z"}, {"A".."Z"}), {"Names.1", "Names.2"})
in
    #"Split Column by Character Transition"
```

***Original***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

If you absolutely MUST use VBA, here is code that will return the splitted names as a 2 column range.  There is a Function which uses regular expressions to split the name; and a macro (Sub) which takes the values in Column A, and returns the splitted names in another area.  Edit to suit your particulars

```
Option Explicit
Function splitNames(ByVal S As String)
    Dim MC As Object
    Dim vTemp(1)
    
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .ignorecase = False
    .Pattern = "([A-Z][A-Za-z\s]+[a-z])([A-Z][A-Za-z\s]+[a-z])"
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        vTemp(0) = MC(0).submatches(0)
        vTemp(1) = MC(0).submatches(1)
    End If
End With

splitNames = vTemp
    
End Function

Sub splitIt()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant, rRes As Range, v As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    vSrc = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set rRes = .Cells(1, 10) 'or set to original if you want to overwrite
End With

ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 2)
vRes(1, 1) = "Name.1"
vRes(1, 2) = "Name.2"
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    v = splitNames(vSrc(I, 1))
    vRes(I, 1) = v(0)
    vRes(I, 2) = v(1)
Next I

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
```